# Automatically send an email using the responses from a Google form

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, automation

I'm trying to create a Google Form where coworkers can send and email anonomysly to another coworker, giving them praise or words of encouragement. The form layout is pretty simple. The first quetsion is just an input for the user to place the email address they want to send their response to, and the second question is a paragraph style question, where they're free to write in what they want. I also have a very basic email template in a Google Doc.

The issue is, I'm not sure what code I need to use in the AppScript on the google responses sheet, and I'm not sure how to make it so that the recipient doesn't see who sent the message.

I've used this coding, but it doesn't send to the email I submitted on the form, and it obviously sends it as an attachment, which I don't want. I want it to send as just a standard email.

```
function respondToFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log('respondToFormSubmit ran');

  fncGetContentToSend();
  fncSendEmail();
}

function fncGetContentToSend() {
  Logger.log('fncGetContentToSend ran');

  var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  //Convert spreadsheet to PDF
}

function fncSendEmail() {
  Logger.log('fncSendEmail ran');

 // Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID');
 GmailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'Caregram Message', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
};
```

Comment: Which onFormtSubmit trigger are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple email from a form submission script:

The first question is the email recipient
The second question is the subject
The third question is the body of the email

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(e.values[1],e.values[2],e.values[3])
}
```

Create an onformsubmit trigger for a spreadsheet

You will become the sender of the email